# sprite animation

Tags: animation, graphics, computer-vision, sprite, multimedia

I study "Fundamentals of Multimedia : Ze-Nian Li , Mark S Drew" but , I didn't understand the meaning of "sprite". now Can someone explain me the meaning of "sprite"?
and please explain me one algorithm for it.
tnx

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia:

> In computer graphics, a sprite is a two-dimensional image or animation that is integrated into a larger scene.

However, I'm not sure if it can indeed be an animation. As far as I know the term a sprite is a *single-frame still image*. Multiple sprites of a figure can be used to make an animation.

For example, in a side-scrolling 16-bit game (such as the old Mario game), there's a sprite for mario standing still, two sprites for a running mario, etc. Upon input of the player the corresponding sprites are shown, animated or not.

I also think SO is not the best site to ask such a question, I recommend [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)